# execute a main class from a jar

Tags: java, jar

I have a jar which contain two main class Class A and Class B. In the manifest i have mentioned Class A . Now i have to execute classB from the same jar . what should be the command.

I dont prefer to make two separate jars.

Thanks

Answer (score 53, accepted):

This will do the job: `java -classpath yourjar.jar youpackage.B`

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you create a Main class that accepts an argument? That argument will decide whether to execute Class A or Class B then.

Comment: This is already supported directly by the java command, no reason to write custom code to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Use a command-line switch to identify whether Class A or Class B should be executed.