# How to Run a specific Main class from a jar

Tags: java, jar, program-entry-point

I have a jar file having 2 java classes both having Main methods. Is there a way I can specify while running the jar file, which class to call ?
I know that manifest file can be modified to specify the Main class but since only one class can be mentioned, that does not help. 
I checked the below links, but those dint solve the problem:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474666/how-to-run-a-class-from-jar-which-is-not-the-main-class-in-its-manifest-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474666/how-to-run-a-class-from-jar-which-is-not-the-main-class-in-its-)

manifest-file
[execute a main class from a jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070100/execute-a-main-class-from-a-jar)

It gives NoClassDefFoundError.

Comment: java -jar <jar file> <class name>

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run a class from Jar which is not the Main-Class in its Manifest file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474666/how-to-run-a-class-from-jar-which-is-not-the-main-class-in-its-manifest-file)

Answer (score 13):

```
java -cp target/your_file.jar your.package.name.YourClass
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a class that acts as a controller. In its main(), invoke other classes based on arguments passed. Add this as the Main-class in manifest

Answer (score 0):

Write a Main class in which the main method calls the actual method depending on the command line argument passed. Add this Main class in the manifest.