# Classnotfound when running program from command prompt

Tags: java, spring, java-batch

When I run my java program from the command prompt, the program does not not run because of a `ClassNotFound` error. But the class I see is there in a jar file which is on the classpath. That same program when I run from Eclipse works.Not sure as to what I am missing here.Thanks.I was trying to run the following command from my windows dos prompt:`C:\softwares\SpringBatchExample4>java -cp "target/dependency-jars/*:target/spring-batch.jar" org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner spring/batch/jobs/job-read-files.xml readJob`.And I looked into one of the jars under target\dependency-jars to confirm that the jar file has the CommandLineJobRunner class.

Comment: probably you need to provide the required libraries while running from cmd.

Comment: can you show the command you are running?

Comment: Thanks.I was trying to run the following command from my windows dos prompt:C:\softwares\SpringBatchExample4>java -cp "target/dependency-jars/*:target/spring-batch.jar" org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner
spring/batch/jobs/job-read-files.xml readJob

Comment: Please add the command to the question and format it as code. You can edit the question.

Comment: Thanks @Stefan.Done.

Answer (score 1):

When running a JAR file from command line you have two options for specifying the classpath:

1. Using the -classpath or -cp command line argument, followed by a space and a list of full paths to all classpath entries delimited by a semicolon (Windows) or colon (Linux/Unix);
2. Using the Class-Path entry in the main JAR manifest where other rules apply.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no Main-Class entry in your manifest file, you might need to specify the class containing the `main` method on the command line like this:

```
java -cp MyJar.jar com.example.MyMainClass
```

See also:

- [How to run a class from Jar which is not the Main-Class in its Manifest file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474666/how-to-run-a-class-from-jar-which-is-not-the-main-class-in-its-manifest-file)
- [execute a main class from a jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070100/execute-a-main-class-from-a-jar)

Comment: I was trying to execute the following command.Seems to be correct:C:\softwares\SpringBatchExample4>java -cp "target/dependency-jars/*:target/spring-batch.jar" org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner
spring/batch/jobs/job-read-files.xml readJob